# Resources for Pell's equation

Tags: reference-request, concept-motivation, number-theory

What is the best way to introduce Pell’s equation on a first elementary number theory course? Are there any practical applications of Pell’s equation? What are the really interesting questions about Pell’s equation? Are there any good resources on Pell’s equation.

Comment: Have you tried a web search?  Gerhard "Really, Have You Tried It?" Paseman, 2015.07.15

Comment: Peek at http://www.imomath.com/index.php?options=615, for instance.

Comment: If you don't know how it fits into your course, and why you'd want to consider it, better leave it out...

Comment: There is a nice chapter in Stillwell's number theory text. It has a bit about the rational approximation mentioned in the answer below. Also, the problem of finding the first solution from which the others can be generated is considered in that chapter.

Answer (score 3):

Keith Conrad gave a presentation in 2008 that addresses your question,
e.g.:

> Pell solutions lead to good rational approximations to $\sqrt{d}$:

---

[image: KConrad]

          

<sup>(PDF download presentation from [http://www.math.uconn.edu/~kconrad/](http://www.math.uconn.edu/~kconrad/ross2008/pelltalkOSU.pdf).)</sup>

---